# Auto start android java application when USB is connected to mobile?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, start-activity

I'm trying to start an android application whenever any hardware is connected to mobile's USB port.

What I'm doing is creating a BroadcastReceiver and and registering it in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
          android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
          android:resource="@xml/device-filter" />
</receiver>
```

and inside onReceive() method of BroadcastReceiver I'm doing the following

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED") {
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

but it is not working.

I'm surely able to start the application if I'm putting the intent-filter and meta-data to the activity in the Manifest file. But that I don't wanna do because that starts the test activity.

How do I make this work?

Such that whenever I connect some hardware to my mobile then my application starts automatically from the Broadcast Receiver.